# Is there a place on the internet where I could find actual Star Trek episode scripts?

Tags: star-trek, online-resources

Through the years I have purchased a few Star Trek scripts. I even have a DS9 script a buddy of mine mistakenly took off set and dazzled me with at Christmas years ago. As neat as those are to own, they are impossible to search. Is there a place on the internet where the Star Trek show or movie scripts can be obtained in digital format?

(Sometimes I remember a quote and would love to find it. From time to time the internet delivers. Occasionally it does not. I want to have a resource to find quotes as I think of them.)

Comment: “they are impossible to search” — impossible? Nonsense. A true fan would have already transcribed them onto a dedicated *Star Trek* scripts computer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes: [Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/), a fan-made but very reliable site.

From the site's front page:

> This is your one-stop site for who said what and when on televised Star Trek and Doctor Who.
>
> These pages have been created for educational and entertainment purposes only, and the content is decided entirely at my whim.
> They are not here for you to copy onto your own website, so kindly respect that and just link in.

Chrissie, the site runner, has produced transcripts for **all episodes of Star Trek (and also Doctor Who)**. It's a fan-made site - Chrissie is not affiliated with either ST or DW - but very well-made and very reliable.

For example, [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/189.htm) is the transcript for the TNG episode *First Contact*, and [here](http://search.freefind.com/find.html?si=98804524&pid=r&n=0&_charset_=UTF-8&bcd=%C3%AF%C2%BF%C2%BD&query=yacht) is an in-site search for the term "yacht". [Here](http://search.freefind.com/find.html?si=98804524&pid=a) is the advanced search page, and [here](http://search.freefind.com/find.html?id=98804524&map=0&page=0&ics=1) is a site map.

She also links from this site's front page to [another site](http://scriptsearch.dxdy.name/) for Star Trek script searching. Currently this site isn't working (at least for me), but I thought it was worth mentioning in case this is just a temporary downtime.

<sub>As an aside, this site is very useful in finding quotes quickly to provide canon answers to questions on SciFi Stack Exchange ;-)</sub>

Comment: Another aside: if you like Star Trek, this site is a trap, and you might end up spelling hours upon hours reading things...

Comment: Why is it named Chakoteya?

Comment: @1252748: in honour of Chakotay?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite My thought as well. I just can't imagine _why_ though..

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in rand al'thor's answer, [Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net) is very useful, but if you're interested in the original scripts (with scene directions and such) rather than transcripts, you can find all the scripts for the movies, TNG and DS9 (but few or none for other Trek series) at [st-minutiea.com](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/).

Incidentally, if you don't already know, Google does allow for restricted searches of all the websites whose URL starts a certain way. For example, if I want to search all the Chakoteya pages for a certain word or phrase, I can [put the search terms into the Google search bar along with site:www.chakoteya.net](https://www.google.co.uk/search?&q="get+the+cheese+to+sickbay"+site:www.chakoteya.net).

If I’m looking for a phrase, it should be put in quotation marks in the google search, so Google doesn't just look for the individual words. And if I want to search just within a particular Trek show such as TNG or Voyager, I can use a more specific URL beginning, like site:www.chakoteya.net/NextGen or site:www.chakoteya.net/Voyager.